# How to enable bash auto-completion for a function?

Tags: bash, ssh, autocomplete

I have read this tutorial on bash auto-completion [An introduction to bash completion](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1) and I am trying to get the same auto-completion that is already done for `ssh` for one of my functions (that is loaded from `.profile`); which acts pretty much as an *alias*.

What I am trying to do is : get the same auto-completion, that is provided by default for `ssh` (which is the function `_known_hosts`; do `complete -p | grep ssh` and you will get `complete -F _known_hosts /etc/init.d/ssh`), and get it for my own function (which is installed like you woul install an alias, and that in fact does a `scp` and then an `ssh` with the original argument)

Comment: This seems like a vague question, try to be a little more concrete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The completion function for `ssh` here is `_ssh`.

You can see this with `complete -p ssh` (it should also have been in your `grep` output) though it appears to be auto-loaded and so will not show up until *after* you have used it once in that session.

Anyway, that being said you should just be able to hook `_ssh` up to your function as well I would think.

```
complete -F _ssh myfunc
```

Comment: so, now my function (called "connect") has an attached auto-complete function (_ssh) but it does not work unless i do an auto-complete for ssh. how does this loading mechanism work? and how do you "subscribe" for it? 
we tried creating a link from a file "/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/connect" pointed to the /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ssh file (that holds the _ssh function); _ssh is still not found.

Comment: and then we tried creating a file /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/, with a function inside called _connect that just delegates to _ssh. this results in an error not finding the _connect.

Comment: eventually, my friend got it: added file /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/connect that does    . /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ssh
complete -F _ssh connect

Comment: The autoload appears to be based on that file as you suspected but the actual connecting of the two is done in that file. That is it would seem that the `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/connect` would get run on attempted completion of `connect <tab>` but if that script doesn't run `complete -F _ssh connect` it won't register the completion correctly. So you need your own script in that location that runs that command.

Comment: I did not create a new command like OP, but re-used an existing one (I added my own docker pssimple subcommand). I wanted to add it to the list of original docker completions. It took some trial-and-error, but the solution is to do like Belun said: `. /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/docker` to get access to the original completion building function _docker, then rebuilding the array with our own words added: `complete -W "pssimple" -F _docker docker`.

I put these two lines in my .bashrc

Answer (score 0):

Check also this question : [How to enable autocomplete subcommnads on function that's call kubectl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539852/how-to-enable-autocomplete-subcommnads-on-function-thats-call-kubectl)

It allowed me to make aliases like `alias ks='kubectl -n kube-system`, `alias kc1='kubectl --context c1'` working with autocompletion.

It relies on complete-alias : https://github.com/cykerway/complete-alias