# How to enable autocomplete subcommnads on function that's call kubectl

Tags: bash, autocomplete, kubectl

Let's imagine you want to save your time writing all `kubectl` command: `kubectl describe pods` in shorter way: `k d p`.

So the solution is to add function to `~/.bashrc`:

```
k() {
  cmd_kubectl="command kubectl"
  case ${1} in
    g)
      shift
      kubectl_get="${cmd_kubectl} get"
      case ${1} in
        p)
          shift
          ${kubectl_get} pods "$@"
          ;;
        d)
          shift
          ${kubectl_get} deploy "$@"
          ;;
        n)
          shift
          ${kubectl_get} ns "$@"
          ;;
        i)
          shift
          ${kubectl_get} ing "$@"
          ;;
        j)
          shift
          ${kubectl_get} job "$@"
          ;;
        *)
          ${kubectl_get} "$@"
          ;;
      esac
      ;;
    d)
      shift
      kubectl_desc="${cmd_kubectl} describe"
      case ${1} in
        p)
          shift
          ${kubectl_desc} pods "$@"
          ;;
        d)
          shift
          ${kubectl_desc} deploy "$@"
          ;;
        n)
          shift
          ${kubectl_desc} ns "$@"
          ;;
        i)
          shift
          ${kubectl_desc} ing "$@"
          ;;
        j)
          shift
          ${kubectl_desc} job "$@"
          ;;
        *)
          ${kubectl_desc} "$@"
          ;;
      esac
      ;;
    *)
      ${cmd_kubectl} "$@"
      ;;
  esac
}
```

But I'd like to save an effort and improve it more, so my question is:

## How to enable auto-completion on this function to allow fill e.g. the name of the pod?

### Usage:

`k d p` -> `Tab` -> `k d p nginx` (result)

I tried to think up thanks following references, but probably I'm not enough experienced Linux user/developer to compose the final solution.

- [How to enable kubernetes commands autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53444924/how-to-enable-kubernetes-commands-autocomplete)
- [How to enable bash auto-completion for a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072473/how-to-enable-bash-auto-completion-for-a-function)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/68175/how-to-create-script-with-auto-complete

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Been contemplating doing something like this and  although I'm sure there are ways to improve (design wise) it but I'd still say pretty good attempt. Autocomplete in this context seems pretty hard though, doesn't it? Like you would need the function to be aware/query the pods when executing the command? Maybe using a grep instead could at least help funnel it down e.g. `k d p nginx` which would actually translate to `kubectl describe pods | grep "nginx"` But maybe you're really looking at autocompleting for a specific use case. Bookmarking this nonetheless!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't count on it will be easy task. :) 
Do I understand well you mean to use grep in autocompletion logic? Maybe I'm absolutely out and cannot imagine the solution.

Answer (score 5):

I also wanted to make it easier to write `kubectl` commands, but I solved it in a slightly different way.

I will describe this method below as I think you may find it useful.

---

I keep all the necessary files in the `~/.bash_completion.d` directory but you can modify it depending on your needs.

```
$ mkdir ~/.bash_completion.d
```

First, I enabled kubectl autocompletion as described in the Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/included/optional-kubectl-configs-bash-linux/#enable-kubectl-autocompletion):

```
kubectl completion bash > ~/.bash_completion.d/kubectl
```

Then I downloaded [complete-alias](https://github.com/cykerway/complete-alias) - automagical shell alias completion:
**NOTE:** More information on `complete-alias` can be found [here](https://github.com/cykerway/complete-alias).

```
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cykerway/complete-alias/master/complete_alias > ~/.bash_completion.d/complete_alias
```

Next I created the `kubectl_aliases` file with the aliases I want to use:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_completion.d/kubectl_aliases
alias kgp='kubectl get pods'
complete -F _complete_alias kgp
alias kgd='kubectl get deploy'
complete -F _complete_alias kgd
alias kgn='kubectl get ns'
complete -F _complete_alias kgn
alias kgi='kubectl get ing'
complete -F _complete_alias kgi
alias kgj='kubectl get job'
complete -F _complete_alias kgj
alias kg='kubectl get'
complete -F _complete_alias kg
```

Finally, we can execute commands from the files in the `~/.bash_completion.d` directory and check if it works as expected:

```
$ source  ~/.bash_completion.d/kubectl
$ source  ~/.bash_completion.d/complete_alias 
$ source  ~/.bash_completion.d/kubectl_aliases
```

After typing `kgp` and pressing `Tab` twice,  we got a choice of Pods:

```
$ kgp 
app-1      nginx      webserver
$ kgp app-1 
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
app-1   1/1     Running   0          5m28s
```

Comment: To have aliases for every combination of command and subcommands is pretty easy way. But I prefer using the subcommands and trying to find the convenient solution to reach it. Anyway, still thank you for your effort.